# Issue with a simulink simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

So i have been running a simulink system to output the acceleration of a electric vehicle for a certain voltage. However i keep getting the same "Too many outputs" error. I have linked my screenshots for the system, code and error.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your function looks good to me. Could be something elsewhere in the block diagram. I tried to replicate your block diagram. It seems to run, maybe change this file to your transfer function and see if it works: https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Car%20Dynamics

Comment: Could you happen to specify which version of Simulink/MATLAB you are using?

Comment: So i am using the 2018b version.

Comment: Hello Michael. For some reason even basic simulations kept displaying the same error. So i decided to do a clean reinstallation and the issue seems to be resolved. Thank you for the help sir.